# Dynamic fetching for relations in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, relation

I want to be able to dynamically load the relations of my entity, depending on which RestService got called.

Entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Buyer buyer;
    // some more attributes
}

@Entity
public class Buyer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    // some more attributes
}
```

RestController class:

```
@GetMapping
public Iterable<Order> getAll() {
    // here I want JPA to NOT load the buyers for the order
    return orderRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Order get(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    // here I want JPA to load the buyers for the order
    return orderRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(id)).orElseThrow();
}
```

None of the two fetchtypes `LAZY` and `EAGER` or json annotations (like `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonIdentityInfo`, `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`) seem to make this possible as far as I understood and tried.

If this is not possible, maybe someone can explain how to solve this problem then. On the one hand I sometimes need those relations in my frontend to display some values and on the other hand when I always load them I get huge performance problems or infinity recursions.

Comment: You may be looking for `@EntityGraph`.

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JPA supports your use case directly.

One option is to create the same entity twice - one with eager and the other with lazy. Switch them in the methods.

Another option is to use a DTO (Data Transfer Object) as the response, instead of the entity class itself. You will have to write a mapper logic to convert an entity to DTO though.

Comment: There is a way @EntityGraph is exactly doing this.